# How do I use a FUSE server independent of the Linux kernel?

Tags: fuse

Normally, when using a FUSE server (aka FUSE module or FUSE filesystem) the Linux kernel acts as the FUSE client.  They talk a protocol that is semi-documented, but mostly only ever looked at by kernel authors or libfuse authors.  I would like to try interacting with a FUSE server directly in my own application, independent of the kernel, as a child process of my own program.  In other words, I want to write a FUSE client.

I found [this protocol document in the libfuse wiki](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Protocol-Sketch) and I could start experimenting with this, but first I have to figure out *how* to launch the FUSE server.

When I mount sshfs, the process list shows me

```
sshfs $HOST:$PATH $MOUNTPATH
```

and the file descriptors according to /proc are

```
0 -> /dev/null
1 -> /dev/null
2 -> /dev/null
3 -> /dev/fuse
4 -> 'socket:[7464782]'
```

I assume the socket is the SSH connection.  The /dev/fuse is what I'm trying to figure out now.  Did the kernel open that file handle and pass it to the fuse program as descriptor 3? or did sshfs open /dev/fuse itself?  If the FUSE server is connecting to the kernel, how could I get it to connect to a pipe I provide it, instead?

More generally, can someone describe the initialization sequence between the kernel and userspace that leads to the `client <-> server` pipe?  This is the part I can't find any documentation about.